# css issue with table outside from div

Tags: css, datatables

I can't manage css for my table, I tried different things without any success.

As you can see the table is outside of my div

What I'm looking for:

The table must be inside my "Logs" div.

The data must be display in one line (I think that do the job) `<table class="blueTable table-striped table-bordered" id="blueTable" style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;">`

The div "Logs" must be in center of the screen (because the table start too much to the right)

Here an image with data sample

I'm using dataTable for my table

[image]

My css code:

```
    table.blueTable {
        font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
        border: 4px solid #555252;
        background-color: #E8E8E9;
        text-align: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table.blueTable td, table.blueTable th {
        border: 1px solid #555555;
    }

    table.blueTable tbody td {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    table.blueTable thead {
        background: #494949;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #0D1F24;
    }

    table.blueTable thead th {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        border-left: 2px solid #050C0E;
    }

    table.blueTable thead th:first-child {
        border-left: none;
    }

    table.blueTable tfoot td {
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    table.blueTable tfoot .links {
        text-align: right;
    }

    table.blueTable tfoot .links a {
        display: inline-block;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        color: #398AA4;
        padding: 2px 8px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```
    <main role="main" class="container">
        <div class="card" style="width:100%">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class='text-center'><i class="fab fa-reddit mr-2"></i>Logs</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pr-2 pl-2">
                <table class="blueTable table-striped table-bordered" id="blueTable" style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>users_id</th>
                            <th>users_name</th>
                            <th>users_uid</th>
                            <th>users_email</th>
                            <th>roleid</th>
                            <th>isActive</th>
                            <th>created_at</th>
                            <th>updated_at</th>
                            <th>updated_by</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <?php
                        $getProfile = getProfile($conn, $_SESSION["users_id"]);
                        $allUsers = selectAllUsers($conn);

                        if ($allUsers) {
                            foreach ($allUsers as $key) {
                        ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="block" style="width:auto"><?php echo $key["users_id"] ?></td>
                                    <td class="block" style="width:auto"><?php echo $key["users_name"] ?></td>
                                    <td class="block" style="width:auto"><?php echo $key["users_uid"] ?></td>
                                    <td class="block" style="width:auto"><?php echo $key["users_email"] ?></td>
                                    <td class="block" style="width:auto"><?php echo $key["roleid"] ?></td>
                                    <td class="block" style="width:auto"><?php echo $key["isActive"] ?></td>
                                    <td class="block" style="width:auto"><?php echo $key["created_at"] ?></td>
                                    <td class="block" style="width:auto"><?php echo $key["updated_at"] ?></td>
                                    <td class="block" style="width:auto"><?php echo $key["updated_by"] ?></td>
                                </tr>
                        <?php
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <!-- Jquery script -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#blueTable').dataTable({
                "iDisplayLength": -1 // to display all rows
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: my bad I found the solution `<main role="main" class="container-fluid">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the issue the point is to use `class="container-fluid"`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/